# Hi, I want to merge sublists to one list

Tags: python-3.x, merge, sublist

**Problem:**

1. locate the text:  ["X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475"]
2. Extract the 5 digits (for example: 0.8475) from the following link (a text file):
3. calculate the average without sum function...
   https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt?PHPSESSID=f3eb9b379b33fa412909c5123798b393

**Attempt:**
skip any lines that is not start with 'X-DSPAM-Confidence:' locate the key words and found the 5 digit numerals, convert them into string and then convert them into float then list, however when try to use for loop, it did not summarise all the floats in the list. I think the problem is python thinks adding 0 to every iteration in every list, so to solve that problem i need to merge the sublists in num1, but I do not know any simple way to do it...(and this assignment is suppose to be beginner friendly, so I assume there shouldn't be need for advanced/complex python code?)
Please help!

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    
    count = count+1
    findpos = line.find(':')
    #print(findpos, count)
    values = line[findpos+2:26]
    num = str(values).rstrip()
    num1 = [float(num)]
    add = 0
    for i in num1:
        add = i + add 
    print(type(num1), add)
    

print("Done")
```

```
result:
Enter file name: mbox-short.txt
<class 'list'> 0.8475
<class 'list'> 0.6178
<class 'list'> 0.6961
<class 'list'> 0.7565
<class 'list'> 0.7626
<class 'list'> 0.7556
<class 'list'> 0.7002
<class 'list'> 0.7615
<class 'list'> 0.7601
<class 'list'> 0.7605
<class 'list'> 0.6959
<class 'list'> 0.7606
<class 'list'> 0.7559
<class 'list'> 0.7605
<class 'list'> 0.6932
<class 'list'> 0.7558
<class 'list'> 0.6526
<class 'list'> 0.6948
<class 'list'> 0.6528
<class 'list'> 0.7002
<class 'list'> 0.7554
<class 'list'> 0.6956
<class 'list'> 0.6959
<class 'list'> 0.7556
<class 'list'> 0.9846
<class 'list'> 0.8509
<class 'list'> 0.9907
Done
```

Comment: You don't need to manage a list, you just have to sum up all values and keep track of their count.

Comment: thx, got it fix, the problem lies in the numbers not have a proper storage, so by assigning the numbers into a new variable, does the trick, i.e. `if count is 1:
 num1=values` and do that for 27 numbers, now python can calculate the average!